# Systemd delaying restart of a failed service, appears to add a 30 sleep

Tags: systemd, kill, systemctl

(Originally posted this on stackoverflow but was asked to move it here.)
I have a python daemon running as a service, sometimes several of them are running for different processes (p0, p1, etc.) that need the same function. What I've noticed when a service fails, is that sometimes it takes a a significant amount of time for the service to come back up 2 to 3 minutes. When typically I have seen services come back up in seconds.

I had a script run `kill -9` on the processes to test that systemd would restart the services and print out `systemctl status myapplication@p1` every 30 seconds until the service was running again, for 3 of these services running.
What I noticed when one or more of the services takes longer than expected to come back up at the end of their status messages there is this `sleep 30` at the end of the CGroup and the PID for it changes between each call of the `status` command.

```
    * myapplication.service - my application service for p1.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapplication@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2022-03-25 14:48:27 UTC; 26s ago
Cntrl PID: 1335258 (myapplication)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9505)
     Memory: 3.3M
        CPU: 1.442s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-myapplication.slice/myapplication@p1.service
             |-1335258 /bin/bash /path/to/application/myapplication start p1
             |-1336794 sudo -u admin -i python /path/to/application/myapplication.py start p1
             |-1336795 logger
             |-1336802 -bash --login -c python \/path\/to\/application/myapplication\.py start p1
             `-1336830 sleep 30



* myapplication.service - my application service for p1.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapplication@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2022-03-25 14:48:27 UTC; 56s ago
Cntrl PID: 1335258 (myapplication)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9505)
     Memory: 3.3M
        CPU: 1.444s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-myapplication.slice/myapplication@p1.service
             |-1335258 /bin/bash /path/to/application/myapplication start p1
             |-1336794 sudo -u admin -i python /path/to/application/myapplication.py start
             |-1336795 logger
             |-1336802 -bash --login -c python \/path\/to\/application/myapplication\.py start p1
             `-1336919 sleep 30



* myapplication.service - my application service for p1.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapplication@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2022-03-25 14:48:27 UTC; 1min 26s ago
Cntrl PID: 1335258 (myapplication)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 9505)
     Memory: 3.3M
        CPU: 1.447s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-myapplication.slice/myapplication@p1.service
             |-1335258 /bin/bash /path/to/application/myapplication start p1
             |-1336794 sudo -u admin -i python /path/to/application/myapplication.py start p1
             |-1336795 logger
             |-1336802 -bash --login -c python \/path\/to\/application/myapplication\.py start p1
             `-1336998 sleep 30



* myapplication.service - my application service for p1.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapplication@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-03-25 14:49:58 UTC; 25s ago
    Process: 1337069 ExecStart=/path/to/application/myapplication start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1337603 (python)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 9505)
     Memory: 7.2M
        CPU: 1.541s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-myapplication.slice/myapplication@p1.service
             |-1337603 python /path/to/application/myapplication.py start p1
             |-1337659 /bin/sh -c sudo timeout 15 sudo tcpdump -n -i lo udp port 1234 2> /tmp/capture.txt > /dev/null
             |-1337660 sudo timeout 15 sudo tcpdump -n -i lo udp port 1234
             |-1337662 timeout 15 sudo tcpdump -n -i lo udp port 1234
             |-1337663 sudo tcpdump -n -i lo udp port 6343
             `-1337664 tcpdump -n -i lo udp port 6343
```

My unit file doesn't have any restart delay as part of it

```
[Unit]
Description=my application service for %i.

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/path/to/application/myapplication start
ExecStop=/path/to/application/myapplication stop
ExecReload=/path/to/application/myapplication restart
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Why does this delay occur, as it isn't regularly, sometimes it happens, sometimes it does not? Why is the PID for the sleep changing? Initial thought was that it is a new sleep after a restart attempt but looking at the `status` output there was no restart, the `Active: activating (start) ...` time is unchanged until the service is restarted.

---

I've done a bit of playing about now and I think it may be due to me running the `kill` command as a one liner `kill -9 <p1-PID> <p2-PID> <p3-PID>` when I separated it out to

```
kill -9 <p1-PID>
kill -9 <p2-PID>
kill -9 <p3-PID>
```

I'm not running into the 30 sleep for the services. Still needs more testing to be sure, but it's looking that way just now.

But I'm still curious as to why the `sleep 30` appeared?

Comment: See also `StartLimitBurst` (=5) and `StartLimitIntervalSec` (=10) in `man systemd.unit`, though I don't think this is the cause here. You are limited by default to 5 restarts in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Your service contains `Type=forking`.  That means your unit expects your `ExecStart=` command to `fork()` and then exit.  The service will remain in `activating (start)` as long as `ExecStart=` is still running. When `ExecStart=` does end, `systemd` will choose one of the spawned processes (`MainPID`) and enter the `active (running)` state.

Your `ExecStart=` program appears to be a bash script.  This script probably looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u admin -i python /path/to/application/myapplication.py start p1 | logger &

while /bin/true; do
    sleep 30
done
```

There are a few things wrong with that script, but the part that should be interesting to you is the `sleep 30` at the end.  Your main process is running, but systemd won't enter the `active (running)` state until that `sleep 30` finishes.  You see a new PID each time because a new `sleep 30` is constantly being called.

A well behaved script would create your application and then quit immediately. It is possible that your script is waiting for feedback that the application has started properly before exiting, and that would be fine, but it clearly isn't getting the feedback it is waiting for, so you would need to dig deeper to find out why not.

However, I think it's more likely that your script is waiting for your application to exit before it quits.  Something like this:

```
python myapplication.py &
PID=$!

while ps | grep -q $PID; do
    sleep 30
done
```

The reason I think that is because it sounds like you are `kill`ing `python`, not the `ExecStart=` script.  This means the unit will remain in `activating (start)` until that `sleep 30` finishes.  Then it will check if the PID of your python application is still present (it isn't) and only then will your script stop.

Another part of that script that bothers me is the use of `sudo`.  `sudo` is meant to authenticate an interactive user.  It is not intended to authenticate scripts.  Instead, a more elegant solution is to use `User=admin` in your service.

I see two solutions. Option 2 is by-far my favorite:

1. Edit `/path/to/application/myapplication` and remove that `while` loop.
2. Use a simple service and skip that script completely.  It looks like it was written for another init system (it explicitly starts its own logger which is not needed these days), then modified to block when called in a shell.  `systemd` does all of that for you, so I bet that script isn't required at all.

```
[Unit]
Description=my application service for %i.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/application/myapplication.py %i
User=admin
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If this doesn't help, please post the contents of `/path/to/application/myapplication`